Micrometer and Spring WebClient Logs Missing Trace ID in subscribe and onStatus Methods
I'm experiencing an issue with logging in a Spring Boot application where the trace ID is not appearing in the logs generated inside the subscribe and onStatus methods of a WebClient call. I have configured Micrometer to include the trace ID in all logs, but it seems to be missing in these specific locations.
Important Notes:
I have verified that the trace ID is correctly logged in filters attached to the WebClient, which indicates that the tracing setup is functioning properly.
Below is the relevant code snippet where I'm encountering the problem, with comments highlighting the specific areas of concern.
spring boot version 3.3.0
java version 21
dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>

configuration
@Bean()
    public WebClient webclientBean(WebClient.Builder builder) throws SSLException {
        return builder
                .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
                        .builder()
// logs in the next filters work fine and contains trace id 
                .filter(WebClientFilter.logRequest())  
                .filter(WebClientFilter.logResponse())  
                .filter(WebClientFilter.handleError()) 
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(WebClientFilter.httpClient()))
                .build();
    }


this code in main class

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    }

usage of web client to make http call (here is the issue)
  public Object webClientDispatchPost(Object input, String endpoint) {
        return webClient.post().uri(endpoint).body(input != null ? BodyInserters.fromValue(input) : BodyInserters.empty()).retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, (r) -> {
                    log.info("trace id does not logged here !!!");
                    // do something 
                })
                .bodyToMono(Object.class)
                .subscribe(response -> {
                            log.info("trace id does not logged here !!!");
                        },
                        error -> {
                            log.info("trace id does not logged here !!!");
                        },
                        () -> log.info("trace id does not logged here !!!"););
    }


1- I tried to access MDC from subscribe method but it's empty but I can see trace id when I tried to access MDC from the filters
2- I tried to add this dependencies but it does not work
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Is RabbitMQ really relevant to the problem? Consider to minimize the scope for easier triaging by whoever is going to look into your problem.

No, It is not relevant to the problem, I have removed rabbit MQ code from my question
